# Visual Studio 2012 32bit compilation on 64bit system

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, 32-bit

I have recently wanted to build a dll plugin for a program. Problem is, the program is 32bit, but by default my Visual Studio 2012's C++ compiler creates 64bit binaries, and I don't know how to change it - I've found the Configuration Manager and tried to create a new platform but there's only x64 as an option.

Am I trying to set the target architecture in the wrong place or what? Is there an update or something I can download so that I can create my dll? Is there a compiler switch that I can set somewhere?

Hope this screen helps:

[image]

Comment: Your active platform is win32 (which means 32 bit) so what is your problem? You may like to test this [pe inspectore](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) which is very helpful.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that your project is **not** creating 64-bit executables.  You've got the Win32 configuration as the default.  So when it prompts you for a **new** platform it will only offer the 64-bit option.  Whatever your problem might be, it is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

To build for 32 bit architecture, you have to open project properties window, and then Linker options.

Set the value of Target Machine option to MachineX86.

Answer (score 2):

- Check the Build Configuration (Build -> Configuration Manager), and ensure that your DLL project for 32-bit is selected.
- Check the linker settings, and ensure correct path is given.
- After build, check that .DLL is produced at correct path, and is 32-bit (should be!).

You can use Dependency Walker to check if DLL is 32-bit or 64-bit.
You also didn't mention if `/clr` option is used with this DLL or not. With `/CLR`, managed binary is produced. Though this option wouldn't alter *bit-ness* of the binary, you can just check if this is the case.